# No route matches missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, routes

I'm new at Rails and I've seem similar problems, but I can't solve mine.

My routes:

```
resources :users do
    resources :items
end
```

My models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :items
end
```

HTML:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= item.id %></td>
  <td><%= item.code %></td>
  <td><%= item.name %></td>
  <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_item_path(item) %></td>  <---- error
```

And I'm getting the same error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"items", 
:user_id=>#<Item id: 1, user_id: 1, code: "123", name: "test", 
quantity: 12, , created_at: "2014-02-11 15:45:30", updated_at:
"2014-02-11 15:45:30">, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You need to include the user as well since its a nested route. So something like:

```
<td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_item_path(@user, item) %></td>
```

Comment: shouldn't this be: edit_user_item_path(item.user, item)?

Comment: You could do that, but you usually use nested routes because you want to assign the `@user` variable to be used in the view. If you're not using `@user` then you might not need a nested route.

Comment: Can you tell me for the case that i use form_for ? what should i put?

Comment: `<%= form_for([@user, @item]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>` Docs are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: In a similar instance of this for me in rails 4, I had to say `edit_parent_child_path(params[:parent_id], child)`  In case that helps anyone else.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you are using nested resources:

```
resources :users do
   resources :items
end
```

So when you have a link:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_item_path(item) %>
```

It will lack one `user_id` so the easy to check the issue is using `rake routes`. And it will list the routes like this:

```
edit_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
```

You can see the routes above and check it with the link, you will see it does not have `user_id`. That's the main reason!

Comment: This helped me "click" all pieces of information together, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You've missed `user_id` in the following path:

```
edit_user_item_path(user_id, item)
```

format you are able to find just running `bundle exec rake routes | grep edit_user_item`

Comment: I had NEVER consider piping the output of `bundle exec rake routes` to grep. Brilliant.

Answer (score 4):

The object `item` is being passed instead of the required id.

```
<td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_item_path(item.id) %></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_item_path(@user, item) %>

and in item form
<%= form_for([@user, @item]) do |f| %>  ... <% end %>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).